# Adding lazy constraint in python-Gurobi interface

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to add some lazy constraints to the first stage of a stochastic programming problem. For example, the optimal solution shows me that locations 16 and 20 are chosen together which I don't want to so I want to add a lazy constraint as follows:

```
   First Stage
       x1 + x2 + ... + x40 = 5
       z_i,l <= x_i   i=1,..,40  and l=1,2
   Second Stage
       ....
   def mycallback(model,where):
       if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
          sol = model.cbGetSolution([model._vars[s] for s in range(1,40)])
          if sol[16] + sol[20] == 2:
             Exp = LinExpr([(1,model._vars[16]),(1,model._vars[20])])
             model.cbLazy(Exp <= 1)

  model._vars = x
  model.optimize(mycallback)
```

But after running this function, locations 16 and 20 are still in the optimal solution. Could you please let me know how should I attack this issue?

Comment: Check your use of the range() function.

Comment: When I check the model._vars[s] for the specified range, it gives me the optimal value (0-1) for each location correctly. Could you please specify more how to check the range?

Comment: In your code above, _vars[i] != sol[i] for i=16,20

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not resolved my problem yet. I changed my primary question. Could you please tell me what exactly I should change in the callback function? I am writing it like couple of examples that exist in the Gurobi website.

Comment: Try changing `for s in range(1,40)` to `for s in range(40)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the test

```
if sol[16] + sol[20] == 2:
```

is comparing the sum of two floating point numbers with an integer using equality.  Even if you declare decision variables to be integer, the solution values are floating point numbers.  The floating point numbers don't even need to have integer values.  Gurobi has a parameter [IntFeasTol](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/intfeastol.html#parameter:IntFeasTol), which determines how far a value can be from 0 or 1 and still be considered binary.  The default is 1e-5, so 0.999991 would be considered an integer.  Your check should something like

```
if sol[16] + sol[20] > 1.5:
```